# How to generate and connect to database from entity data model in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: database, model

I read a few of the corresponding questions here but none of them seems to solve my problem.

I have a **.edmx** file. I want to generate a database from this model, so I do the following:

Right-click on the entity data model, then Generate Database From Model. Generate Database Wizard appears and asks where to save a generated **.sql** file. I can only click on Finish.

Now I have an sql file. I run the script - still inside Visual Studio - and it says everything is ok, rows affected etc.

So I suppose I have a database now. (Although I don't know the path of the .mdf file, nor can I look into it to see if the tables have been generated correctly, but that's not the point.)

Visual Studio says I'm connected, though I can't see this database in Server Explorer.

So I run the program, and an exception appears:
EntityExcpetion was unhandled. The underlying provider failed to open.

What's the story with this?

Answer (score 0):

When in your `.edmx` design window, click anywhere outside of an entity, and view the properties window (`F4` is it is not visible).  In the properties window, look at the connection string value, and determine if it is valid.  You can also see where it is connecting, and thereby confirm the tables are generated correctly.

The connection string is also saved in the `App.Config` file.

It seems like you are logged in to the database using Visual Studio, but the login does not have all the details correct in the `App.Config` or there is a permissions issue between the two logins.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your query in Visual Studio, does it ask you to connect to SQL Server? if so, what is the server you are connecting too? I'm thinking you are creating your database in a different server that the one in your project's connection string.

Comment: I have only one server so I cannot connect to another.

Comment: @GáborBirkás There is definitely a discrepancy on where you are creating your tables and where your app is connecting.

Comment: Can you tell me where the generated .mdf file is located? I can't find it in Start menu. If I find that I'll be able to change the connectios string.